# Can't find the organization ID at IBMCloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I'm new at IBMCloud, I'm following a tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/IoT-Weighing-Scale/ but after register an account, I don't see any organization ID. I've been checking all the options in the main panel but can't find those 6-digits ID.

I need that in order to register the device (Esp32) https://***organization_ID***.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/dashboard/#/overview

I have a LITE account for *Internet of Things Platform Starter*

Edit:
When login in internetofthings.ibmcloud.com I see no organization registered:
[image] when I click in Register, it takes me to the Bluemix panel.. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The org id could be found accessing one of your devices details, it is the first Id in the list

Comment: I'm just trying to register the first device, so I don't have any device's list with details yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged into Watson IoT Platform's UI in a browser, the 6 character orgId is visible in the URL.

For example, in the screenshot below the orgId is "hldtxx".

[image]

Comment: Note you'll need to provision an instance of the Internet of Things service from IBM Cloud first: once you do this, you can launch the service and get to the UI.

Comment: When I login in the internetofthings.ibmcloud.com website, I see that there's not ID. I just edited the original post with a screen-shot.
Once I click in _register_ it takes me to the main panel in bluemix but nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

you need to first register to https://console.bluemix.net/ then from Catalog select Internet of Things service, deploy it. Then go to IBM Cloud dashboard, select the IoT Service, click on Launch button and you'll be taken to xxxxxx.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

Comment: I'm registered on https://console.bluemix.net/, I've selected _Internet of Things Platform Starter_, I've given a name and started the app, when it's running and I click the URL, it takes me to https://pesoapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/ but still, I can't find where is that organization ID for https://organization_ID.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/dashboard/#/overview

Comment: You can't access the https://organization_ID.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com by going to pesoapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net. 
From IBM Cloud dashboard, under "Cloud Foundry Services" section (should be the last one from the page), you should see an IoT Service called: pesoapp-iotf-service. Click on that and you should see the Launch button that will take you to organization_ID.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com. If you don't have it, then I think you need to delete the app and recreate it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

After signing in, on the top menubar, click "Manage" and select "Access (IAM)". Then, from the left navigation menu, click "Users". Toward the upper right, under "**Account:**" (see image below), hover your mouse over the 'i' symbol to locate the Account ID.

[image]